# ListPlot: Plotting large data fast

Tags: plotting, graphics, front-end, rendering, system-performance

Mathematica produces fantastic-looking graphics, but it can be slow on large data sets. Here is an example for a (random) time series:

```
rv = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 10^5];
```

Plotting this takes quite some time:

```
t = AbsoluteTime[]; ListLinePlot[rv, PlotRange -> All]
AbsoluteTime[] - t (* Put this line into the NEXT cell, and evaluate both cells together*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The option `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"` has no effect.
Turning off antialiasing makes it much faster (but if you increase the data size to 10^6 instead of 10^5, it is still VERY slow. A time series of 10^6 points is quite reasonable in my applications):

```
t = AbsoluteTime[]; 
Style[ListLinePlot[rv, PlotRange -> All], Antialiasing -> False]
AbsoluteTime[] - t (* This line in separate cell! *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Reducing the number of `MaxPlotPoints` makes it much faster, but completely distorts the shape of the data:

```
t = AbsoluteTime[]; ListLinePlot[rv, PlotRange -> All, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000]
AbsoluteTime[] - t (* This line in separate cell! *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**: I am interested in tricks to show the data quickly without distorting the shape. I am showing here my own solution, which is quite a bit of a hack, but it works. Are there more elegant solutions?

### Edit:

My own answer, previously posted as part of the question, is now an independent answer ([see below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29799/58))

Comment: FYI you can use `Timing` or `AbsoluteTiming` to time the execution of a command, instead of having to subtract time values manually.

Comment: I don't think it works for the plotting, as Timing[] only reports about the time spent in the Kernel.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood your question. Are you asking about the time it takes the resulting `Graphics` object to render on screen? `AbsoluteTiming` might cover that as well, since it measures wall time, not CPU time, though I forget when exactly it stops. (BTW, if rendering is the bottleneck, saving the plot to a rasterized image file can be a good strategy)

Comment: @David `AbsoluteTiming[]` doesn't cover rendering of the graphic.  It only times how long it takes for the kernel to finish, and the rendering is done by the front end only after the `Graphics` expression has been sent to it.  Generally, both `Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming` measure the time it takes for the kernel to finish (not front end), but the former is CPU time while the latter is wall time.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi To be honest, I am not completely clear about these either.  I do know that `AbsoluteTiming` won't measure graphics rendering time (because I tried it in the past, though not with v8).

Comment: Related: "[Speed up `ListLinePlot`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6560095/590388)."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### My own solution:

Note: I have earlier posted this answer as part of the question itself. I have now removed it there and put it as independent answer.

(see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560095/speed-up-listlineplot/6618163#6618163) for a simpler version of this)

```
Options[fastListPlot] = {plotPoints -> 1000, AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRange -> All, Options[ListLinePlot]} // Flatten;
fastListPlot[data_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Module[{plotData=data, lengths, range = Automatic, points = OptionValue[plotPoints]},
        While[Depth[plotData] <= 2, plotData= {plotData}];
        lengths = Length/@plotData;
        If[NumericQ[points],
           plotData = Partition[#, Floor[Min[lengths]/points]]& /@ plotData;
           plotData = Flatten[{Min /@ #, Max /@ #}\[Transpose]] & /@ plotData;
           range = {1, Max[lengths]}
                   ];
        ListLinePlot[plotData, FilterRules[{opts, DataRange -> range,Options[fastListPlot]},Options[ListLinePlot]]
        ]
    ]
```

The trick is within the `If` statement: I partition the data into a number of blocks corresponding roughly to the resolution of my screen (usually 1000 or less, option `plotPoints`). Then I determine the Min and Max of each block, and draw a zig-zag line from min to max to min to max...

My solution, as presented, works for simple lists (i.e. of `Depth` 2), and also for lists containing more than 1 data set (`Depth` 3).

Examples:

```
fastListPlot[rv, PlotLabel -> "Fast"]
fastListPlot[rv, plotPoints -> All, PlotLabel -> "Normal, Slow"] 
fastListPlot[{rv,rv/2}, PlotLabel -> "Fast, more than 1 dataset"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, very nicely, the visual structure of the data is preserved, in particular the peaks in the data are preserved and still visible - despite only plotting 2000 points (first plot) instead of 100.000 points (middle plot).

The following doesn't quite work correctly (problem with `DataRange`):

```
fastListPlot[{rv,Take[rv/2,10000]}, plotPoints -> All, PlotLabel->"Original"]
fastListPlot[{rv,Take[rv/2,10000]}, plotPoints -> 1000, PlotLabel -> "Incorrect scaling"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 38):

Many posters already suggested good answers. I am just adding some explanation behind this behavior. Also, I have to warn that this is *my* understanding, and I couldn't find any reference. So, please take it with grain of salt. I am more than happy to stand corrected, if found wrong.

## Problem

It is a rendering issue. And it is in fact Windows' GDI+ related issue (and probably Apple too). I tried my best, but couldn't find related Microsoft KB (which I know there is...).

Anyway, this is what is roughly happening. If you have lines defined by `Line[{pt1, pt2, ...}]`, system graphics API treat it as a single path (with multiple segment). Now, in a single path case, the API, especially the rasterizer is trying to see whether each pixel is intersected by multiple segments. The reason? Because of the opacity. Compare these two images (very exaggerated, but the idea is there).

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};

{Graphics[{Thickness[.1], Opacity[.3], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]}],
 Graphics[{Thickness[.1], Opacity[.3], Line[Partition[pts, 2, 1]]}]}
```

[image]

If you don't treat the self-intersection, what you end up getting is something like the second result (transparency accumulated in self-intersection points). Which is very bad for many cases. Now it shouldn't be a problem when opacity is 1, but unfortunately if you use anti-aliasing, then you are in effect introducing a different opacity, this should be dealt. This is no problem with *multi-path* case (like the second image), since in that case, you can just accumulate pixel values at each pixel.

To prove it, compare the following point configuration and speed difference:

[image]

The same number of points, but the rendering of the second one is much faster.

Now, back to our problem. When we are using `ListLinePlot` without any options (or just `PlotRange->All`), the process is very close to what Leonid's `myListPlot` is doing. Which means that it will generate a long chain of `Line[{pt1, pt2, ...}]` and the self-intersection routine will kick in. If you see the original result closely, you will see that in fact, the resulting graphics has a lot of self-intersection in pixel-res space (it does computation on pixel-level).

## Solutions

In fact, Mr.Thomas already got his own answers.

1. Turing off anti-aliasing (by `Style[..., AntiAliasing->False]`). This way, the rasterizer spend a lot less time processing intersections, thus much much faster.
2. Sub-sampling. There are multiple ways, `MaxPlotPoints` is one, Thomas' code is another, and much more.
3. Cheating by making multiple paths:

Well, this solution isn't going to give you super boost. Just in case you absolutely need anti-aliasing, and also need to use all the points. Look at a part of my first example:

```
Line[Partition[pts, 2, 1]]
```

You will see that we are essentially turning `Line[{pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, ...}]` into `Line[{{{pt1, pt2}}, {{pt2, pt3}}, {{pt3, pt4}}, ...}]`. As long as the opacity remains 1, the result should be about the same (except `JoinedForm`, but in our case it is no concern). The benefit of the second form is that now it is *not* considered to be a single path. So, the rasterizer will think that it is multiple-path, and no self-intersection treatment.

I modified Lenoid's `myListPlot` a bit so that it does this task.

```
ClearAll[myListPlot2];
Options[myListPlot2] = {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Automatic}};

myListPlot2[pts_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{pts1, pts2},
  pts1 = Developer`ToPackedArray@
    Transpose[{N@Range[Length[pts]], pts}];
  pts2 = Partition[pts1, 2, 1];
  Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Line[pts2]}}}, 
   FilterRules[{opts, Options[myListPlot]}, Options[Graphics]]]]
```

Now, time to prove the theory. With the same data set `rv`, here is the timing comparison between `myListPlot` and `myListPlot2` (`myListPlot` is faster than `ListLinePlot` so it is enough).

[image]

Well, about twice as fast. Frankly, it is not that practical, just theoretical interest :)

## Addendum

Szabolcs found some bundling going on at 500 (Not sure it is Windows specific or number is exactly that, but bundling is true), which makes me experimenting with different segmenting--instead of just 2, partitioning it at 3, 4, ... etc. And I got all different speed result (getting faster, then slower again). If you use `Partition` it drops the tail (and I personally am still learning all complex syntax, so...), but it shouldn't make that much of difference, in my opinion.

So, the problem is probably not just affected by the self-intersection, but also the bundling. It gets more interesting / complex :)

Comment: Somehow this got cut off.  BTW I'm also suffering from slow line-drawing speed right now, and I found that in my application (some generative art experimentation), more than 50% of the time is spent in `ToBoxes`, not in actual rendering.  Strangely, using something like `graphicsExpr /. Dispatch[{Graphics -> GraphicsBox, Line -> LineBox}]`, etc., can be near-instantaneous while `ToBoxes` can take more than 10 seconds for the same input.  I'm wondering if `ToBoxes` really *needs* to be so slow, or maybe there's a bug that causes a performance problem?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit post before finishing it...

Comment: Very cool and informative - big +1.

Comment: A question about the benchmarking method:  why is `Rasterize[g]` slower than `t=AbsoluteTime[]; g`, then `AbsoluteTime[] - t`?  Before I used the `Rasterize` method because I did not realize I need to put `AbsoluteTime[] - t` in a separate cell (if it's in the same cell, it gives an incorrect result).  In a random test I just did, `Rasterize` took 5.5 seconds while just showing the result in the the front end took 4.0 seconds.  Is that 1.5 second spent on sending the data back to the kernel through MathLink? (One 360 px raster image shouldn't take long to send)

Comment: That was illuminating, thanks!

Comment: I experimented a little bit with this.  I noticed that something like `Graphics[{Thick, Opacity[0.2], 
  Line@Accumulate@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 2}]}]` does get darker as the line gets longer.  It seems that a line "start to overlap itself" after 500 points.  `Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.3], Thickness[0.1], 
   Line[Sequence @@@ 
     Table[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {i}]]}], {i, 1, 500}]`  I wonder if this is system-dependent or not.  Is it Mathematica that breaks the link into 500-point segments before passing it to the OS or it's GDI+ that's doing this.

Comment: This example shows too that this is not just of theoretical interest.  It's important to be aware of this behaviour when making pretty figures!

Comment: Instead of `Partition[Riffle[pts1, Rest[pts1]], 2]` you could use the simpler `Partition[pts1, 2, 1]`.

Comment: @celtschk, good one thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes, indeed there is a bundling with hard coded number (not sure it was 500), and as far as I remember it was true for Windows, but I am not sure it is _only_ for Windows...

Comment: To avoid losing the final points for larger partitions, you can use the extra arguments `1,{}`, e.g. `Partition[pts1,20,19,1,{}]`.

Answer (score 25):

## Short version

Use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html).

## Long version

My fire-and-forget approach to this is interpolating the data first and then plotting it, which is (much to my surprise) orders of magnitudes faster than directly plotting the dataset.

In general, `ListPlot` and friends really plot the whole list, they make no selection of points. A million points dataset will produce a million plotted points (and then some, consider connecting them with lines etc).

Let's have a look at an example, plotting $\sin(x)\sin(x\,y)$. For eyecandy, this is what it looks like:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[x y], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 64]
```

> [image: Direct plot of sin(x)sin(xy)]

Let's generate the corresponding dataset, a list with entries of the form $\bigl(x, y, f(x, y)\bigr)$.

```
step = .1;
data = Table[{x, y, Sin[x] Sin[x y]}, {x, -3, 3, step}, {y, -3, 3, step}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

Now let's compare the plot performance of this dataset, once directly given to `ListPlot3D`, and then first converted to an `InterpolatingFunction` via `Interpolation[data]`, and then plotted as a continuous function using `Plot3D`.

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[ListPlot3D[data]]
```

> ```
> 4.220737 seconds
> ```

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[ListPlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 32]]
```

> ```
> 17.555031
> ```

```
First@Timing[
    interpolation = Interpolation[data];
    Plot3D[interpolation[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
]
```

> ```
> 0.182330 seconds
> ```

```
First@Timing[
    interpolation = Interpolation[data];
    Plot3D[interpolation[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 32]
]
```

> ```
> 0.426254 seconds
> ```

As you can see, the interpolated version is faster by over an order of magnitude. In practical use, this method has two shorcomings, however, these can easily be resolved:

1. You have to specify the data range for the `Plot` function yourself, as the `InterpolatingFunction` generated by `Interpolation` doesn't explicitly show its range. *Solution:* This information can easily be extracted from the `InterpolatingFunction` object via `Part` ("double brackets"): `interpolation[[1]]` yields `{{-3., 3.}, {-3., 3.}}`, which is of the form `{{xMin, xMax},{yMin, yMax}}`.
2. The plot is of lower quality than the original dataset, since smoothing etc. is done automatically. To solve this general problem, use `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` as usual.

## Solution, ready to copy+paste

```
FastListPlot[data_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[
    {interp},

    interp=Interpolation[data];
    Plot[interp[x],{x,interp[[1,1,1]],interp[[1,1,2]]},opts]
]
FastListPlot3D[data_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[
    {interp},

    interp=Interpolation[data];
    Plot3D[
        interp[x,y],
        {x,interp[[1,1,1]],interp[[1,1,2]]},
        {y,interp[[1,2,1]],interp[[1,2,2]]},
        opts
    ]
]
```

Comment: This downsamples, but it does not avoid aliasing effects.  Instead one could just use `MaxPlotPoints` for downsampling.  You can look at the original thread Thomas is linking to to understand what the problem is and why this doesn't solve it.  (In short: if there are outliers / rare large values in the data, this approach will still effectively filter them out)

Comment: Copying my example from the comments there (which is btw included by the OP too): `rv = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 10000];
if = ListInterpolation[rv];
{min, max} = First@if["Domain"]` Then compare `Plot[if[x], {x, min, max}, PlotRange -> All]` and 
`ListLinePlot[rv, PlotRange -> All]`.  They look strikingly different, i.e. your method does not preserve the shape of the data nearly as well as the OP's method.

Comment: I have to disagree with your first post: Downsampling with `MaxPlotPoints` makes things much worse on my computer.

Comment: I could make your version `FastListPlot` to look like the original `ListLinePlot` by using 2 changes: Use `InterpolationOrder->0` in the definition (otherwise: one gets artifacts close to the x-axis for the particular data set `rv` defined in the OP), and, in the Plot itself, go up to `MaxRecursion->11`. This last step, however, made it very slow, slower than the original ListLinePlot. There might be more appropriate options for `Plot` than `MaxRecursion` to achieve better sampling, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @Thomas That's a situational option that depends on the data set. You can still set those options manually when using `FastListPlot` as you would for other plots.

Comment: @David I agree. However, the point is of course to have a function that will perform a fast plotting without distorting the shape of the data. This purpose contradicts the need to play with options and find their ideal settings, because that would require to compare with the original (remember, I don't want to plot the data with the original `ListLinePlot` function, as it is too slow in many cases, but instead I want to quickly see how the data looks).

Comment: It's a matter of what you want to plot. I use my approach for mostly smooth datasets (phase diagrams for example) where it works very well, and MaxPlotPoints doesn't. If you've got a large dataset and really need to see all the detail (example?) it's probably not the way to go.

Comment: The example would be electrophysiological data recorded from neurons. Neurons spike; in a sense the spikes could be called "outliers" within the background noise. But that's exactly where the real information is! So the data is anything but smooth. And a 50-sec recording at 20-kHz sampling gives you 10^6 data points.

Comment: Don't know why I never thought of doing this, but you've just saved me oodles of time...

Comment: Is `FastListPlot` prepared to accept a list of datasets?  ;)

Answer (score 22):

This might not answer all the speed-problems, but it is my solution to plot enormous datasets. By using a dynamic interface it is possible to only show (and keep in memory(?)) a small range of the whole plot, which makes visual analysis of and interaction with the plot much more fluid. The key point is to only update the `PlotRange` dynamically and not the entire plot.

It works nicely even when downsampling/interpolation is not possible, because e.g. each datapoint must be plotted. Both horizontal and vertical ranges can be set, and I also added some other functionality to test that it works as expected.

```
(* number of datapoints and some random datasets *)
n = 10^5;
lineData = Table[Sin[x] + RandomReal@{-.5, .5}, {x, 0, n, 1}]; 
pointData = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution@2, n];
timeData = RandomInteger[{0, n}, n/2];

DynamicModule[{plot, window = 0, range = {100, 2}, showLine = True, 
  showPoints = True},
 Panel@Grid[{
    {"x position", Row@{Slider@Dynamic@window, Spacer@10, Dynamic@window}},
    {"x-y range", Row@{Slider2D[Dynamic@range, {{100, 1}, {3000, 30}}], Spacer@10, Dynamic@range}},
    {"show line", Checkbox@Dynamic@showLine},
    {"show points", Checkbox@Dynamic@showPoints},
    {Item[Dynamic@Button["Copy", CopyToClipboard@plot, ImageSize -> 60], 
      Alignment -> Left], SpanFromLeft},
    {Item[Dynamic[plot = Show[
         If[showLine, 
          ListPlot[lineData, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
           PlotRange -> All], Graphics@{}],
         If[showPoints, 
          ListPlot[pointData, Joined -> False, PlotStyle -> Red, 
           PlotRange -> All], Graphics@{}],
         ImageSize -> {600, 200}, AspectRatio -> Full, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
         PlotRange -> 
          Dynamic@{{Max[n*window - range[[1]], 0], 
             Max[n*window, range[[1]]]}, {-range[[2]], range[[2]]}},
         PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled@.01, Scaled@.02}, 
         GridLines -> {timeData, {}}, GridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel@.9],
       TrackedSymbols :> {showLine, showPoints}], Alignment -> Left], 
     SpanFromLeft}
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left, Left}, Center}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1  This should be the answer.  You have "quality" and "interpretability" first and foremost.

Answer (score 18):

This will work low-level and produce a mostly equivalent plot, but be quite a bit faster:

```
ClearAll[myListPlot];
Options[myListPlot] = {
   AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {All, All}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Automatic}
};
myListPlot[pts_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6],
  Line[
    Developer`ToPackedArray@
      Transpose[{N@Range[Length[pts]], pts}]]}}}, 
  FilterRules[{opts, Options[myListPlot]}, Options[Graphics]]]
```

For example:

```
In[249]:= rv=RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2],10^5];

In[250]:= (im1=myListPlot[rv]);//AbsoluteTiming
Out[250]= {0.0029296,Null}

In[251]:= t=AbsoluteTime[];im2=ListLinePlot[rv,PlotRange->All];
AbsoluteTime[]-t

Out[252]= 0.4423828

In[253]:= 
(im1/. (AxesOrigin ->_):>AxesOrigin ->First[Cases[im2,(AxesOrigin-> x_):>x,Infinity]])===im2
Out[253]= True
```

Comment: The speed bottleneck really seems to be the rendering. For comparison: on my machine I get: Original ListLinePLot: 1.78 sec; Your myListPlot: 1.4 sec; my fastListPlot: 0.18 sec

Comment: @Thomas Oh I see. I was suppressing the output and therefore did not observe this. You must be right. Was worth a try, anyways.