# Transparency rendering problems in Mathematica 10 (Mac)

Tags: plotting, bugs, mac-os-x

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

For some weird reason, they apparently changed the styling of contours in ContourPlot for 10.0. Here is a comparison of the results for V9 and V10 (first 9, then 10):

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
    ContourShading -> None,  ContourStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.008]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica 9 output] Version 9

[image: Mathematica 10 output] Version 10

Firstly, can I override the coloring? I would like to keep the solid colors that were in V9. And secondly, where do those dark spots come from? Is this a bug?

Edit: yes, this does look like a bug. The dark spots are only visible in the Mac version.

Interestingly enough, for about half a second after the output appears, what I see on the screen is similar to what `Export` produces (shown below). The only difference is that the lines are thinner in the exported .png (another bug?). After those 0.5 seconds, another level of transparency kicks in and I see what is shown in the top picture below.

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
    Contours -> {.9}, ContourShading -> None, 
    ContourStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.17]}}]
```

[image] <- What I see.
[image] <- What `Export` produces.

Comment: You may try setting `PlotTheme` to traditional?

Comment: @YiWang you meant `Classic`? It's okay but it adds a strange blue frame even with `Frame->None" added. And the dark spots are still suspicious.

Comment: I do not get any spots, using V10, windows 7 ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HcLMG.png)

Comment: @Nasser, great, so it's a Mac specific bug...

Comment: it sounds like it I assume as I do not see the result you show on my windows 7 system.

Comment: `ContourStyle -> {{Red,Opacity[1],Thickness[0.008]}}` gives the same contour line colors as in v9.

Comment: @kguler right, thanks! But do you see those spots, too?

Comment: @level1807, i don't see the spots in Windows 8.0.

Comment: @kguler installed the Windows version... yep, no spots there.

Comment: Here is a wild guess: Might these spots come from overlapping ends of line segments (caps), and they become darker due to additive effects and the transparency? See this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5406/58

Comment: @Thomas interesting... If that's the case, then I guess there is no _simple_ way to fix this.

Comment: @level1807 Presumably (but I don't know) rendering in general (and of transparent objects in particular) uses OS functionality and is therefore platform specific, which might explain why it occurs on Macs but not Windows.

Comment: I can reproduce the dots you see under Linux. Also, I think that @Thomas is correct. Try this: `Contours -> {.9}, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> {{Red,Thickness[0.1]}}`

Comment: @sebhofer Indeed. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: @sebhofer there is even more to this problem, as my experiment with `Export` shows (see the edited post).

Comment: Interesting: They fixed the overlap in 10.0.1, and in 10.0.2 they changed the `Opacity[0.5]` to `Opacity[1]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose two possible solutions:

1. Turn off transparency by including `Opacity[1]` in the `CountourStyle`
2. Use `CapForm["Butt"]` to prevent the line caps from overlapping.  With this solution you can keep transparency on, and the result will look like:

[image]

With `CapForm["Butt"]` theoretically there can still be a slight misalignment, or crack between the lines, but this is unlikely to be visible in practice.

---

**Edit:** Another possible solution is adding the option `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}`, as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1402/12).  I don't know what this does exactly.

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty neat solution. Is there a way to tell if they actually use `"Butt"` automatically in the Windows version? Or anything else..

Comment: @level1807 You could try all possible values in the Windows version and see if it makes a difference. If it does not make a difference, then the most likely explanation is that lines that are specified together, as a single `Line` primitive, are also rendered together by Windows, and transparency is added only after all lines have been rendered.  I would compare `Graphics@{Thickness[0.2], Opacity[0.5], 
  Line[{{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, -1}, {0, 1}}}]}` with `Graphics@{Thickness[0.2], Opacity[0.5], Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
  Line[{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}]}` on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: @level1807 See my update.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this help or not but here is what I got for you.

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ContourShading -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.008]}}, PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I didn't think this is `None` =) Apparently `Opacity[1]` already gave the save effect, but thanks. This question has now transformed into a discussion of rendering bugs.