# ListPlot3D keeps crashing

Tags: plotting, crash

I have some data, and I want to plot it by `ListPlot3D`:

```
image1 = Import["image1.dat", "TSV"];
image1 // Dimensions
(* -> {150000, 3} *)
```

I used:

```
ListPlot3D[image1[[1 ;; 50000]], MaxPlotPoints -> 5, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

Although I tried to plot just one third of the whole data, the kernel crashes--let alone when I want to plot all of it.

If I use:

```
ListPlot3D[image1[[1 ;; 10000]], MaxPlotPoints -> 5, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

it returns an empty plot.

Can somebody tell me if they reproduce the crashing by plotting the data? How can I stop the kernel crashing when I plot my data? Does this happen because there are so many points?

The plot is actually consisted of fifteen 2 dimensional decay curves which I want in 3D, and each decay curve is consisted of 10000 points. I added to each point two other coordinates to be able to plot it in 3D.

I use Windows 7, 64 bit and *Mathematica* 9. I have enough RAM too, so I don't think it is because of RAM shortage.

It seems the solution in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/675/1205) works for me, but I want each of those 15 decay curve to be plotted separately, and by using the proposed solution the plot looks like a surface. Also, I want to know the reason for the crash.

Here is a sample of what I'm looking for:

[image]

I used `ListPointPlot3D` to get this, however, it is extremely slow if I rotate the plot to inspect it more. That's why I tried `ListPlot3D`.

[Here is the link to the data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=33453537256006111018).

Comment: Obligatory question, what os and what version of mathematica are you using?

Comment: I use Windows 7, 64 bit and MMA 9.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the crash.

Comment: @Öskå For me it takes 2 minutes.

Comment: @Öskå This is what I get with interpolation.
If I use the first 10000, it returns an empty plot.

Comment: @yashar, `ListPlot3D` will give you a surface rather than 15 separate curves. Why not stick with `ListPointPlot3D` but only plot every 20th data point?

Comment: @SimonWoods O.K I will try that. At first I thought it would decrease the quality of plot.
One other reason to use `ListPlot3D` is that later I need a surface like plot.

Comment: I would go with @SimonWoods's suggestion. Use `ArrayResample` to pick every nth datapoint from each list and use `ListPointPlot3D` on the list of lists