# More efficient ListLinePlots?

Tags: plotting, graphics, front-end, rendering, system-performance

I'm generating grids of `ListLinePlot` objects with hundred thousands of points each, and my notebook gets very slow very fast. IE, I have a hard time scrolling once I add a couple of figures like below.

I suspect it's because I have millions of vector objects being rendered, which seems unnecessary for simple visualization. Is there a nice work-around for this?

[image]

Comment: You should post code not images of code. Also, have you seen [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html).

Comment: Have you seen `MaxPlotPoints`?

Comment: I often group and close cells that have rich graphics when scrolling, only opening the cells when necessary.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140/121

Comment: OK, the collapsing tip seems to do the trick. A reusable contribution to the community could be a modified "ListLinePlot" which acts same args as ListLinePlot, but can handle large datasets without slowing down display too much